# WPF style exception

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have tried to publish my application to a freshly installed Windows 10 PC today and i had an exception, after hours of trying to find what causes this i have managed to get the exception description:

> Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' Line number '3466' and line position '50'.

The code on line 3466 is:

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="brojevidokumenatacbox" Margin="0,106,102,0" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43"  ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate3}" Background="#FF3C3C3C" BorderBrush="#FF5F3333" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle3}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="184">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="258" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle2}"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Specifically, the part that causes exception is: Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle2}"

This is the style:

```
   <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: A freshly installed PC suggests that there are service packs or other updates missing. Check the version numbers of the assemblies you reference, including the .Net Framework version

Comment: Did you define the ComboBox.Static.Background, ComboBox.Static.Border, ComboBoxTemplate and ComboBoxEditableTemplate resources that your style reference?